# webapi frombody xml blank with declaration

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I have a asp.net webapi v2 running katana and using XmlSerializer with a very simple custom Serialization implementation:

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SetSerializer<SalesOrder>(new XmlSerializer<SalesOrder>());
```

XmlSerializer is just a simple implementation of the to System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer abstract class

When calling a Post like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]SalesOrder value)
{
    return value == null || value.SignZoneCustomerNumber.IsNullOrEmpty()
        ? Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        : Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, _service.CreateOrder(value, Request.GetCorrelationId()));
}
```

The value is null when the xml contains a declaration like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
```

Strip out the declaration and send the post it desearilizes fine.

Any idea why the declaration causes deseriazation to fail?

The Model is defined like this:

```
[XmlRoot("Order")]
[Serializable]
public class SalesOrder : BaseOrder<SalesOrderLineItem>
{
    public string PoNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PoDate { get; set; }

    ...more properties...
}
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Turns out it was the encoding that caused the problem
this header works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

other values like UTF-16 and ISO-8859-1 fail
any idea why?

Comment: I have a similar problem on a client application.
Without the ability to mess with the serving application, it seems to me that Web API 2 have a major flaw MS needs to deal with... unless of course that there is a workaround